# How to solve crystal report issue when deploying a asp.net web application in IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I have a asp.net web application and I am using crystal report in it.It works fine when running on localhost but gives the following error when it is deployed in the IIS server

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to
>   interface type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{31E7715A-8AD0-4D1C-958E-C1BE0A6F2D0C}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).mscorlib   at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr
>   pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)

Comment: Sounds like your missing the correct version of an assembly? What OS &CR versions are on localhost & your server?

Comment: Thanks,..... I have solved the issue by enabling 32 bit applications in my application pool

Comment: Post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the issue by enabling 32 bit applications from application pool in the IIS server that I was using to deploy the web application